# Controlling/switching on/off devices via relay board

Tags: gpio, power

I was wanting to use my Raspberry Pi 3 to turn on/off devices.  I found this board which looks like it would do the job:

[http://www.amazon.com/JBtek-Channel-Module-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B00KTEN3TM/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KTEN3TM)

Would this work?  Also curious how to connect that board to my GPIO port.  I think I have an idea, but would like to be sure.  There is:
GND
IN1
IN2
IN3
IN4
VOC

So, would it connect as follows (based on the pinout I found here:  http://blog.mcmelectronics.com/post/Raspberry-Pi-3-GPIO-Pin-Layout )

GND --> 9
IN1 --> 29
IN2 --> 31
IN3 --> 33
IN4 --> 35
VOC --> 2

Is this right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have no problem with this setup. Just remember it is good practice to have the pi switched off when making the connections and check twice that everything is hooked up correctly before switching on.

Comment: Thanks!  I was curious about something else.  I saw another comment on the Amazon comments for the relay board, and the person used ports 26,24,21,19, which are tagged as "SPI", instead of the "GPIO".  Is that correct as well?

Comment: Yes that is correct. They can be used as normal GPIO pins when setup via Python scripts.